# Pointer inside object that is being pointed to changes memory position if object is accessed

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm trying to make this code as generic as possible to help future wanderers.

**A.h**

```
class A {
    protected:
        A* pointToAnother;
    public:
        A();
        func();
}
```

**A.cpp**

```
A::A() {
    pointToAnother = nullptr;
}

A::func() {
    // does something
}
```

**B.h**

```
#include "A.cpp" //Using A.h gave me linking errors

class B {
    protected:
        A* pointToA;
    public:
        B();
        do_something();
}
```

**B.cpp**

```
B::B() {
    A tmp;
    pointToA = &tmp;
}

B::do_something() {
    pointToA->func();
}

int main() {
    B test;
    B.do_something();
}
```

When `do_something()` is called, before `pointToAnother->func()` runs, `pointToA->pointToAnother` correctly points to `0x00000000`. However, once `func()` runs, `pointToAnother` is now pointing at `0xcccccccc` BEFORE running what's inside of `func()`, which breaks my program.

I tried implementing the rule of three, thinking the bug had something to do with destruction, but that had no dice. I ran into a similar problem in another program (modifying an object in a vector by calling a function of said object, only for the previous position in the vector to now be pointing to `0xcccccccc`) that I gave up on.

Thanks

Comment: `pointToA->func();` You have undefined behavior. It might behave different on other platforms or when code is changed. So what?

Comment: `A tmp;` - this object dies as soon as the constructor of B returns.

Comment: How did you run this code? It doesn't compile!

Comment: As for your edit: That's how MSVC implements this in debug versions of your build to make it easier to find these kind of bugs. Still it may differ for release builds, or what other compilers do.

Comment: "Using A.h gave me linking errors" that's because you need to add A.cpp to the list of files being compiled. Including the source file as you're doing it is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:

```
B::B() {
    A tmp;
    pointToA = &tmp;
}
```

In the function, `tmp` is a function local variable. It gets deleted when the function returns and you are left with a dangling pointer value in `pointToA`. If you dereference the pointer later, you invoke undefined behavior.

You can resolve that problem by couple of means.

1. Change the variable `pointToA` to be `objectA`, i.e. change it from being a pointer to `A` to be an object of type `A`.

   ```
   class B {
       protected:
           A objectA;
   ```
2. Allocate memory using `new A` and assign it to `pointToA`.

   ```
   B::B() {
       pointToA = new A;
   }
   ```

If you use the second method, make sure to read up on [The Rule of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) and update your class accordingly.

Comment: So simple, yet I burned so much time on it. Thanks!

Comment: @MasterBob, you are welcome. As long as you learn from these mistakes, it would be ok.